# How do I update the "Secure URL" on a quiz I made so that users can view it again?

Tags: facebook, url

The quiz can't be viewed by any other users, unless the "Secure URL" is updated. But I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means you must have an SSL certificate on the domain that hosts your canvas page. I would recommend rapidSSL.

Here is a general overview of what this entails: http://webnet77.com/SSL-certificates.html

Here is what we do:

1. get yourself host account with dedicated IP or better linux dedicated server
2. ask your host to generate Certificate Signing Request or do it yourself use openssl (don't know how to do it on windows)
3. get cheap ssl certificate (like rapidSSL) 9.90 per year or something just domain verification, google it.
4. send them your CSR
5. wait like 10 minutes
6. find your cert in your inbox attached
7. install it according to your server (Apache uses mod_ssl)
8. test it